# VB.NET How to fill this text box on a webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, textbox, fill

Trying to fill this text box in a webbrowser programmatically.

```
<div class="yt-simplebox-text" contenteditable="plaintext-only">This is a text inside of the textbox</div>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work at all...

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If element.GetAttribute("classname") = "yt-simplebox-text" Then
            element.SetAttribute("value", "wfewfewfwefewfegerg")
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Controls must have a runat="server" property to be visible from code behind.

Is there any reason you're not using an asp:Textbox control? In code behind you can access it directly, without cycling through all the controls in the document.

Comment: The website which I'm trying to fill its textbox is not mine, is the textbox from youtube comment section. I just want to enter a comment programmatically to post it.